# Is this a gennel or just an alley?

Tags: british-english, speech

This is a follow-on from [a question I asked on Movies.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/117782/29139), about the following shot from a TV show:

[image]

I've always called this a gennel (probably more popularly known as a ginnel throughout the rest of the North of the UK), although [according to Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Thesaurus:alley#English) it seems like each region of the UK might have its own name for one.

However, a commenter on that question disagrees and says this doesn't meet the definition of a gennel, which must run between buildings rather than just behind them. For those in the North of the UK who have grown up using these regional dialects, would this be considered a gennel/ginnel/`<insert regional variation here>` or not?

Comment: In the NW of England, that's a 'back' or 'backings'. Contrast the 'back yard' most houses would have, with a gate opening into the back.  As you say, one might expect a couple of ginnels piercing each opposing terrace when they are so long, usually aligned.

Comment: "more **popularly** known as a gennel throughout the rest of the UK". Neither of them is popular in my region, I have never heard either word. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/ginnel) says it is Northern England dialect.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The North West is a very big place, and from what I've seen I'd estimate "ginnel" and "gennel" are both more common than "backings".

Comment: Lexico does not have "gennel".

Comment: @WeatherVane I had always thought it was the most common in South Yorkshire, but according to Wiktionary it's specific to Sheffield, so maybe it's less common than I thought.

Comment: @WeatherVane And yeah, I mentioned the North at the bottom of the question, the "rest of the UK" part was me not thinking. Edited out.

Comment: With the 'back' sense rather than the 'snicket' / 'vennel' sense? We had/have backs (as shown here) _and_ the narrow ginnels piercing terraces.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Okay, I see what you're saying. Not an ginnel or an alley, but a back.

Comment: Running from street to street and ready for trash pickups and truck deliveries, that's an alley in the US. Standard in Chicago.

Comment: [Is this what you're talking about?](https://www.ourdialects.uk/maps/walkway/)

Comment: @Mitch That's an amazing find, thank you, and in the process of typing the question I wondered about whether a "dialect map" for the UK existed and what it would take to build one, but for the purposes of this question I don't think it's an answer - the problem is what the definition of a gennel/ginnel/all other variants are and whether they include alleys like the one in the shot.

Comment: @HashimAziz 1) I don't have a feel for the variation there (I'm AmE) - 'gennel' is entirely new to me2) It just supplies some data to help someone who actually knows what's going on to answer. 3) I bet there are other surveys/maps that might provide more info.

Comment: I hope people are doing their due googliligence and searching for any kind of maps and surveys that might include 'gennel'. To cut off at least one failed path, the New York Times in [their UK/Ireland dialect quiz](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2019/02/15/upshot/british-irish-dialect-quiz.html) does not have a question about such a walkway.

Comment: @Mitch [*The Guardian*](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2016/jun/10/the-end-of-the-alley-or-whatever-you-call-it) has **gas**, **drang** and others.

Comment: And [this](https://www.theanswerbank.co.uk/Phrases-and-Sayings/Question118833.html) turns up **wynd**, **vennel** and **ennog**.

Comment: Note that the OP's question is not about what the synonyms of ginnel or alleyway are, but what that particular thing in the picture is, which might lead to any exposition of subtle differences with the words in this set..

Comment: In Derbyshire we call it a jitty (or sometimes a twitchell), and I think of it as a pathway between two properties  to provide a shortcut between two streets.

Answer (score 3):

My subjective conception of a *ginnel* from growing up in Leeds in the 50s is that it does *not* correspond to what is represented in the picture, which is too wide and open.

What we, as children, referred to as *ginnels* were always narrower and inaccessible to traffic — what my wife (who grew up in Wales and Humberside) calls a *snicket*. But, of course, this proves nothing, as usage elsewhere — even in Leeds — may differ/have differed.

Normally I would not answer a question from such a subjective viewpoint, but in this case it would appear that only an accumulation of such individual recollections will produce an overall picture.

Answer (score 2):

I'm originally from Sheffield. To me, a *gennel* (or entry) ran between houses giving access to backyards and doors - typically one gennel would serve six houses, so three at either side.

The picture depicts what we would call "backs" or "back whacks".

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a still from the BBC's 1980's series
*The Boys from the Blackstuff* showing the actor Michael Angelis who played the character *Chrissie*.  If I'm right then what you are looking at is a *jigger*, the Scouse word for the alley separating rows of houses.  I don't have access to OED here, but [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jigger#Noun_3) gives this definition

> (*dialect, Liverpudlian, dated*) An alleyway separating the backs of two
> rows of houses.

On further reading I see that *jigger* is also mentioned in *The Guardian* article [Weather Vane](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/240807/weather-vane) refers us to.

Now that I have OED to hand I can see that it does mention this, Scouse, definition for *jigger*.

Answer (score 2):

I am a northern incomer but that is a back alley, a ginnel gives me claustrophobia, so it isn't one of them [image: a ginnel from google]

Answer (score 0):

ginnel, gennel, (OED pron. dʒe·nĕl, dʒi·nĕl, gi·nĕl) /ˈdʒɛnəl/, /ˈdʒɪnəl/, /ˈɡɪnəl/), backs, jitty, alley, passage[way], ten-foot*, and many other words are used to describe the passage shown, which is, in fact, "rear-access road" (See [Law Insider](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/rear-access-road)) where a vehicle can get down it, and one of the above where vehicles can't.

According to the OED "Jitty" is quite recent - first recorded 1836 and probably cones from "Jetty"

Ginnel (etc.) is older (early 15th century) and from the French.

Other names probably arise from the great urbanisation of the 19th century and are of a descriptive nature, hence local.

They are also known as a "service road" although this term also encompasses roads that run close to houses, and parallel to, a main road.

The terms are all very local with may be more than one term being used in one town, and any attempt to define one or another word will fail with the cry of "In [insert town] we call them [insert term.]"

**in Hull, Yorkshire where six-foot, and sixteen-foot are also used as a description of the approximate width.*

Comment: Also in Northern Lincolnshire and other areas as well they are known as _tenfoots_. I believe that both _ginnels_ and _snickets_ run from the street to the back of the houses (often to the tenfoot) but a ginnel is covered by the upper floors of the houses whereas a snicket is open to the sky.